# Trying to use ImportXML but am getting "Expected 2 arguments but got 3" error. How should I do it?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am setting up a sheet for tracking stocks. There is a piece of information I am trying to use `ImportXML` to get.  The issue is I want to implement it in a way where the formula will work with all the stocks and not require individual URL customization.

So I can get the `ImportXML` to work just fine when I am specific.
**EXAMPLE:**

```
=IMPORTXML("https://WebsiteInQuestion/quote.ashx?t=V","/html/body/div[4]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[11]/td[6]/b")
```

But that requires specifying a specific stock in the URL.  What I want to do is,
**EXAMPLE:**

```
=IMPORTXML("https://WebsieInQuestion/quote.ashx?t=",**C2**,"/html/body/div[4]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[11]/td[6]/b")
```

Where **`C2`** is the cell with the  ticker for a specific stock. But that is 3 arguments and `ImportXML` won't let it work.

Comment: How about `=IMPORTXML("https://WebsieInQuestion/quote.ashx?t="&C2,"/html/body/div[4]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[11]/td[6]/b")` or `=IMPORTXML(CONCAT("https://WebsieInQuestion/quote.ashx?t=",C2),"/html/body/div[4]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[11]/td[6]/b")`? [Ref1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/37505) and [Ref2](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093592)

Answer (score 1):

use `&` to append C2:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://WebsieInQuestion/quote.ashx?t="&C2*, 
 "/html/body/div[4]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[11]/td[6]/b")
```